# How to get autocompete in PyCharm for parameters?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm pretty new to coding & Python and was using PyCharm. I can get the regular autocomplete for functions (like the Button function below...)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fasjw.jpg)

But I can't seem to get it to appear for the different arguments? Is that possible in PyCharm. For instance, I'd like to see the whole list of arguments available ... such as 'padx', 'state', 'relief', 'fg', 'command' etc... (I'm thinking of something that would be similar to excel where I can see the whole list of all arguments available).

Currently what I have to do as a workaround is to use websites such as https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_button.htm or google search to see what are the different arguments available and then I have to manually type it all as below in without any autocomplete

```
back_btn = Button(root, text="<<", state="disabled",command=lambda: loop(i - 1))
```

Comment: ctrl+p gives you function parameter popups. Is that what you want?

Comment: Hey Ken, yea I saw that but it only tells me **master=None, cnf:dict{}**kw**  .... which doesn't help too much because it doesnt mention anything about the types of arguments that I can add in

Comment: I believe it does include type hints, if those are available.